# What to do when .Net garbage collection is slower than the rate at which objects are being created/deleted?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, lucene, lucene.net

I have a live Lucene index that is updated throughout the day. When several successive batches of updates for the index come through, I want those updates to be available for searching as quickly as possible. Therefore I have to recreate the IndexSearcher.

The problem is that the IndexSearcher can take around 100mb of memory and when a lot of updates are coming through, it can be recreated relatively often and I've noticed the .Net garbage collector seems slow to clean up the reference to the old IndexSearcher object. This results in the memory usage of the process climbing out of control as the collector seems to free up memory from old IndexSearchers more slowly than they are being recreated.

I've found this problem is mitigated by crossing the line into taboo territory and calling `GC.Collect()`, which frees up the memory immediately. The performance impact doesn't seem to be noticeable but as I'm doing something that many advice against, I'd be curious if anyone else has experience of objects being created and released faster than the garbage collector is cleaning them up. I'd be particularly interested if anyone has had this problem with the Lucene IndexSearcher.

I should note that the IndexSearcher is being recreated at peak times around once every 10-20 seconds.

Comment: Sounds indexSearcher is some kind of cache. Please, do not forget is a bad way use cache when you update frequently...

Comment: No it's not being cached. I'm using a single searcher and it's being stored in its own private field. When I recreate it, I simply set the field to a newly-created instance. The old reference then drops and is available for collection.

Comment: I had similar problem in the past. Storing datatables in sessions. The new objects grow more fast than the GC collected. You need the objects and his properties in the indexSearcher collection not be referenced in a long live objects. Ensure no other objects are referencing to the old indexSearcher. If any of the objects in indexSearcher are referenced in other, the old indexSearcher is considered as long live duration object and will be collected in second or third GC generation, not in the gen0 that is you need.

Comment: Yeah, the old searcher is not referenced anywhere after I recreate it, so it's obviously being treated as long-lived.

Comment: are you using the latest lucene version? If yes can you post a test case that reproduces the issue? I am unable to reproduce the behavior you are seeing with the latest lucene version. I'm using a 100gb index. I add 100docs, get a searcher, make 50 random search. I repeated that process in a loop 100 000 times and my app is still at 275MB ram.

Comment: @JfBeaulac - I'm using Lucene.net, which equates to Lucene 2.9.2 at this time. Also my index has 2.8million docs right now and will get up to 200million+ when it goes live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I consider it acceptable to call [`GC.Collect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) if you just released a ton of memory, and the memory can and should be freed now to reduce memory pressure.  The GC does not know this memory is now available until it runs again, and you don't know when that will be.

In your case, you said "it can be recreated relatively often".  If so, calling `GC.Collect` when you recreate it sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for the support - I'm always paranoid that I'm writing bad code when I'm working with areas that I don't know inside out!

Comment: +1 I second the opinion that it is OK where proven to be useful.  But most of the time it's not useful over normal GC behaviour, hence it gets looked at suspiciously all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried configuring garbage collection for the server?  I believe it differs in that GC is on another thread:

[Should we use "workstation" garbage collection or "server" garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707240/should-we-use-workstation-garbage-collection-or-server-garbage-collection)

As for "faster than cleaning them up", if memory is available then the system will grant it to your process.  The garbage collector will collect at various junctions as memory grows, but it will not stop allocations in order to maintain a certain level of memory pressure - the OS manages pressure.

Unfortunately I have no direct experience with Lucene, so my answer is just about garbage collection in general.

Comment: +1 for the link - I didn't know there were two garbage collection modes