# Limiting the number of parallel task with SemaphoreSlim - why does it work?

Tags: c#, task

in MS Docu you can read about SemaphoreSlim:
„Represents a lightweight alternative to Semaphore that limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently.“
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0

In my understanding a Task is different from Thread. Task is higher level than Thread. Different tasks can run on the same thread. Or a task can be continued on another thread than it was started on.
(Compare: "server-side applications in .NET using asynchrony will use very few threads without limiting themselves to that. If everything really can be served by a single thread, it may well be - if you never have more than one thing to do in terms of physical processing, then that's fine."
from [in C# how to run method async in the same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255539/in-c-sharp-how-to-run-method-async-in-the-same-thread))

IMO if you put this information together, the conclusion is that you can’t limit the number of Tasks running in parallel with the use of a semaphore slim, but…

- there are other texts that give this kind of advice ([How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations), see “You can definitely do this…”)
- if I’m executing this code on my machine it seems it IS possible. If I work with different numbers for _MaxDegreeOfParallelism and different ranges of numbers, _RunningTasksCount doesn’t exceed the limit that is given by MaxDegreeOfParallelism.

Can somebody provide me some information to clearify?

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            IRunner runner = new RunnerSemaphore();
            runner.Run();

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class RunnerSemaphore : IRunner
    {
        private readonly SemaphoreSlim _ConcurrencySemaphore;
        private List<int> _Numbers;
        private int _MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;
        private object _RunningTasksLock = new object();
        private int _RunningTasksCount = 0;

        public RunnerSemaphore()
        {
            _ConcurrencySemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(_MaxDegreeOfParallelism);
            _Numbers = _Numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }        

        private async Task RunAsync()
        {
            List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();            

            foreach (int number in _Numbers)
            {
                var task = Task.Run
                    (async () =>
                    {
                        await _ConcurrencySemaphore.WaitAsync();

                        bool isFast = number != 1; 
                        int delay = isFast ? 200 : 10000;

                        Console.WriteLine($"Start Work {number}\tManagedThreadId {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}\tRunning {IncreaseTaskCount()} tasks");
                        await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        Console.WriteLine($"End Work {number}\tManagedThreadId {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}\tRunning {DecreaseTaskCount()} tasks");
                    })
                    .ContinueWith((t) =>
                    {
                        _ConcurrencySemaphore.Release();
                    });


                allTasks.Add(task);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(allTasks.ToArray());
        }

        private int IncreaseTaskCount()
        {
            int taskCount;
            lock (_RunningTasksLock)
            {                
                taskCount = ++ _RunningTasksCount;
            }
            return taskCount;
        }

        private int DecreaseTaskCount()
        {
            int taskCount;
            lock (_RunningTasksLock)
            {
                taskCount = -- _RunningTasksCount;
                 
            }
            return taskCount;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: I've read your question several times, but I don't fully understand what you're asking with regards to why it wouldn't work. `SemaphoreSlim`'s `WaitAsync` method doesn't block a thread, it suspends the execution, and then resumes when it's possible to.

Comment: It is basically a context insensitive counter (be it Thread or Task). It decrements each time you `Wait` or `WaitAsync` and increments on `Release`.

Comment: To Fildor:  Thanks. That's the info I got wrong before. I thought calls to Wait and Release were context sensitive and bound to the calling thread. Maybe I mixed it up with way a lock works, where the identity of the thread, that is acquiring the lock, does matter.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was suspecting. You can easily test the behavior if you do some reentrant stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Represents a lightweight alternative to Semaphore that limits the number of threads that can access a resource or pool of resources concurrently.

Well, that was a perfectly fine description when `SemaphoreSlim` was first introduced - it was just a lightweight `Semaphore`. Since that time, it has gotten new methods (i.e., `WaitAsync`) that enable it to act like an *asynchronous* synchronization primitive.

> In my understanding a Task is different from Thread. Task is higher level than Thread. Different tasks can run on the same thread. Or a task can be continued on another thread than it was started on.

This is true for what I call "Delegate Tasks". There's also a [*completely different* kind of Task](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html) that I call "Promise Tasks". Promise tasks are similar to [promises (or "futures")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) in other languages (e.g., JavaScript), and they just represent the completion of some event. Promise tasks do not "run" anywhere; they just complete based on some future event (usually via a callback).

`async` methods always return promise tasks. The *code* in an asynchronous method is not actually run as part of the task; the task itself only represents the *completion* of the `async` method. I recommend my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for more information about `async` and how the code portions are scheduled.

> if you put this information together, the conclusion is that you can’t limit the number of Tasks running in parallel with the use of a semaphore slim

This is personal preference, but I try to be very careful about terminology, precisely to avoid problems like this question. Delegate tasks may run in parallel, e.g., `Parallel`. Promise tasks do not "run", and they don't run in "parallel", but you can have multiple *concurrent* promise tasks that are all *in progress*. And `SemaphoreSlim`'s `WaitAsync` is a perfect match for limiting that kind of concurrency.

You may wish to read about [Stephen Toub's `AsyncSemaphore`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-5-asyncsemaphore/) (and other articles in that series). It's not the same implementation as `SemaphoreSlim`, but behaves essentially the same as far as promise tasks are concerned.