# multi-thread CPU usage in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu-usage

My Program uses predetermined number of threads that each do independent work.
I use i7-2600 CPU but I shut down the hyper-thread module so it runs 4 threads on 4 cores.
When I run the program with 1 thread the CPU usage is 25% which is perfect since 1 thread is fully used, but when I run 4 or 3 thread I only get 60% CPU, why?

Like I mentioned before the threads are totally independent (there are no locks and no contentions) also when I run the program 4 times with 1 thread I get 100% CPU usage (i.e. when its 4 processes of 1 thread for each process I get proper CPU usage)

Any ideas?

some more info:

1. I'm not using I/O while processing all the needed data is loaded into to the memory, each thread loads its own data prior to processing.
2. I do load the data from a database (using oleDb) but the issue I'm describing happens after the loading while all threads are processing (no loading is done).
3. The numbers are:

   - 2 threads around 40% instead of 50 (85% for each thread).
   - 3 threads around 50% instead of 75 (65% for each thread).
   - 4 threads around 60% instead of 100 (60% for each thread).
4. I use i7 2600 with 16GB memory but the memory usage on that process doesn't come close to that.
5. I ran windows performance monitor to look for contentions there are none.

Comment: Are you making blocking I/O calls?

Comment: it depends what each thread is doing, and how you synchronise between them and what amount of IO you do. Also, in .Net you don't always get each thread on a new CPU

Comment: If they're totally independent then they're probably competing for raw memory bandwidth. That, or cache space.

Comment: Can you post what your thread is doing?

Comment: I'm not using I/O while processing all the needed data is loaded into to the memory, each thread loads its own data prior to processing

Comment: There must be some shared resource you're overlooking. And how's the utilization with 2 threads?

Comment: Memory-manager contention?  With 4 processes there are 4 memory-managers.

Comment: I do load the data from a database but the issue I'm describing happens after the loading while all threads are processing (no loading is done) , 2 threads is similar to 3 and 4.

Comment: Just checking: You're not accessing the Db through LINQ (w/o ToList) , are you?

Comment: 2 threads around 40% instead of 50 (85% for each thread)
3 threads around 50% instead of 75 (65% for each thread)
4 threads around 60% instead of 100 (60% for each thread)

Comment: @RoeyNissim - Good info, add it to the question. Relevant details should not be buried in comments.

Comment: It's clear you're threads are competing for something. Could be Mem bandwidth but that looks unlikely for an i7. More likely a shared queue or a Waithandle. Could be hidden in some unsuspected code.

Comment: I run it on i7 2600 with 16GB memory but the memory usage on that process doesn't come close to that

Comment: Clearly there *is* contention in your program.  The hard ones are the ones you can't see.  Like the lock that protects the GC heap.  You need a concurrency analyzer to chase it down.

Comment: I ran windows performance monitor to look for contentions there are none, what else can I monitor? please I'm open for suggestions

Comment: Yeah, I'd definitely try something like the VS2010 profiler in concurrency mode.

Comment: I think I don't have VS2010 profiler since I use VS2010 pro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to shift your program from workstation to server garbage collection mode. Currently you may use just one garbage collection thread.
The setup is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680014.aspx).
See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707240/should-we-use-workstation-garbage-collection-or-server-garbage-collection) for an explanation/further details.
Do not expect 100 % CPU load after the change, but you will get closer to 100% and increase the spead of it.

Comment: The OP is asking *why* they are seeing the behaviour they are seeing. This does not answer that question.

Comment: He is not saying which GC he is using, but the garbage collector setting maybe why he is not seeing his expected behaviour.

Comment: I switched to serverGC and it seems to do the trick, I guess the GC took some power while it worked in the background

Comment: @RoeyNissim, if this is actually your problem, you're most likely allocating too often. You can probably get significant performance gains by eliminating allocations in the hot paths.

Comment: Svick, what do you mean by "if this is actually your problem" of course it's my problem I posted it. Regarding allocating too often, I don't understand how can you allocate more (or less) then what you need, I allocate when ever I need how can I be allocating too much? also what are hot paths?

Comment: Hot paths are parts of your code that are executed most often, usually inside some loop. You certainly can allocate less, by rewriting your code, for example to use shared instances or object pools or use `struct`s.

Answer (score 1):

The [concurrency visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336027.aspx) will help you here. You will see when each thread is executing, and if all threads are not executing you can see exactly why a specific thread is waiting. If you generate a lot of garbage, the GC may keep threads blocked leading to less than linear scaling. But you will only find out by making a real investigation.

Comment: I think i don't have concurrency visualizer since I use VS2010 pro, any other tool you might recommend?

Comment: You could try the 2011 dev preview, I think it lets you use all features http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Visual-Studio-vNext-Concurrency-Visualizer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while working with .NET Framework v2.0 then i changed the projects target framework to v4.0 it started with 100 % CPU load

Edit: You can watch the CPU usage per threads, simply with

[Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

or

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about "Sysinternals Process Explorer" I will take a look