# What and where exactly is Garbage Collector?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'm coding in `C#` and I'm getting more and more familiar with the `garbage collector` and how it works.

I just realised I didn't know exactly where is the `garbage collector` and what is its representation ?

1. It is a part of any `.Net` application executable file ? That would mean that starting 10 `.Net` applications would result in having 10 different `GC` ?
2. Is it a part of the application called `Runtime` ? That would mean that the previous 10 applications share the same `GC` ?
3. Does the `garbage collector` have a special behavior when using `Asp.Net` (within the code-behind of course) or when using a GUI/service application  ?

Thanks for your precious help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is part of the .net framework. 10 .net applications would have 10 instances of the GC, but all of them will be running the same code (assuming they run with the same framework version).

As far as I know, it is ignorant of the type of application it runs in, so it should behave the same in asp.net as it does in a GUI application or a service.

You can read more about the garbage collector here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx

Comment: It could work differently depending of the type of application and host. This can be configured.

Comment: By running the same code, you mean running the same version of the GC application ? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @vtortola Could you give us more precision ? How would you change this configuration ? Do you mean the xml node <gcServer/> and <gcConcurrent/> as seen here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707240/should-we-use-workstation-garbage-collection-or-server-garbage-collection ?

Comment: @AndyM right, and the element gcTrimCommitOnLowMemory for shared hostings.