# memory leak and GC roots

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, heap-memory, dump, out

Trying to detect memory leak in a webapp.

- Taken heap dump of the app at the time of crash.
- using eclipse MAT to parse the dump.

The collated info from the parsing leads to these 2 conclusions  -

1. Objects occupying more memory dont have GC roots. Essentially whenever GC happens, they get cleaned up.
2. Objects under GC roots occupy significantly less memory. So these may not be the root cause of the memory leak(?).

So does this mean there is no leak happening? and the crash happens because of out of memory error?

EDIT : ADDING ENV INFO

- I am running a java webapp on tomcat 6.
- The webapp is based on openreports (reporting tool)

Adding incoming reference list of the biggest object --

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXPhp.jpg

Here each instance of hash map has a reference from com.opensymphony.xwork2 which is not GC collected. Would this probably be a source of the problem. Because tomcat logs say -

```
SEVERE: The web application [/openreports] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.ActionContextThreadLocal] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext$ActionContextThreadLocal@7c45901a]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@3af7dab3]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
SEVERE: The web application [/openreports] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@258c27bd]) and a value of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext[]] (value [[Lcom.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.InternalContext;@1484fc8d]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

EDIT : Adding stack trace of OOM error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:585)
        at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:193)
        at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.writeExport(TableTag.java:1503)
        at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doExport(TableTag.java:1454)
        at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:1309)
        at org.efs.openreports.engine.QueryReportEngine.generateReport(QueryReportEngine.java:198)
        at org.efs.openreports.util.ScheduledReportJob.execute(ScheduledReportJob.java:173)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
10:01:04,193 ERROR ErrorLogger - Job (90.70|1338960412084 threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:585)
        at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:193)
        at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.writeExport(TableTag.java:1503)
        at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doExport(TableTag.java:1454)
        at org.displaytag.tags.TableTag.doEndTag(TableTag.java:1309)
        at org.efs.openreports.engine.QueryReportEngine.generateReport(QueryReportEngine.java:198)
        at org.efs.openreports.util.ScheduledReportJob.execute(ScheduledReportJob.java:173)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of your OOM error?

Comment: Added the stack trace of oom

Answer (score 0):

Are you running ASP.NET WebForms (not MVC) application? We had a similar issue in our application and these are the points that we ran across. First, I should state that our web farm is composed of a lot of application pools, one for each client of course. Each app pool was given a specific memory limit in order to ensure that clients did not spiral memory out of control and affect other worker processes.

1) Even when objects are not rooted, if they are over 85K they will be placed onto the Large Object Heap, which .NET's GC does not compact. That means that if you have an object that is 100K, it will sit on the LOH. When the object is cleaned up, you will get your 100K back and the GC might decide to put something else in that hole. Since it is not compacted, you can't ever be guaranteed that the space is completely filled. This leaves holes in the space that was not filled up completely and leads to memory fragmentation. The only way to resolve this is to examine your dump file and see what objects are taking up the largest space and identify classes/collections that can be pared down. You will likely see a lot of object arrays and strings as those are typically rather large in cache managers and such.

2) Are you disposing of instances? Waiting until the finalizer thread comes along to cleanup instances should not be the default case, because that can lead to terrible GC performance. Make sure you are disposing all classes that implement the IDisposable interface somewhere in their inheritance. Calling Dispose early means that the resources are released in a deterministic fashion, whereas depending on the finalizer means that cleanup can happen much, much later (if at all).

3) If you are getting OutOfMemoryExceptions, it could be due to two reasons: you ran out of managed memory (rare in the case of a worker process with a limit set as it will be recycled) OR you ran out of Virtual Memory, which is even worse since you are limited to 2GB of Virtual Memory if you are running in a 32-bit IIS application. We also saw this problem in production where the GC was allocating 64MB chunks of heap (32GB in Workstation Mode) and once it was close to the 2GB limit and was not able to allocate more space, it threw the exception (see: [Should we use "workstation" garbage collection or "server" garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707240/should-we-use-workstation-garbage-collection-or-server-garbage-collection)). If this is the case, you are probably leaking a managed resource where it is rooted to something static or you did not cleanup event handlers by removing them with the -= operator.

If you could post your dump file or at least the relevant parts of it, it would be easier to see where the problem lies. But from your short description, these are the items I would look at.

Comment: * ok. so LOH should'nt be a problem in this case, cause gc is happening frequently for this app.
* the 2nd point of yours is wat is happening in the app cause tomcat says that one of the threads is started but never stopped (com.opensymphony.xwork2..)

Comment: Apologies, since your original question was not marked as a Java application, I was under the assumption it was a .NET one. You can safely ignore almost all of the above. As for your issue, it looks like you are storing some data inside of a thread local storage (TLS)? When you application is being torn down, are you removing it and cleaning that up? If this is only happening on application tear down, it shouldn't cause any problems because the whole process should be torn down. However, you should still be a good citizen and remove it. Are you clearing that Hashmap or the thing it belongs to?

Comment: You should also tag which language you are using so others can discover this question.